# ProgressDialog dismiss before the end of the AsyncTask if touched or longer than standby time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have an `AsyncTask` in this form

```
private class AsyncOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           ...
          return null
         }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
            pDialog.dismiss();


        }
```

If the user touch the screen the waiting dialog is closed before the end of the task, if the screen goes in standby during the operation, if I return to the app and the task isn't finished, same issue.

How could I fix this issue? 
Also any suggestion to improve the way I perform async operation that requires times on holo App will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the cancellable property of your ProgresDialog to false:

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
}
```

This makes sure that the progressDialog does'nt disappear when u click anywhere else other than the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the cancellable  property by using this.

Dialog dialog;

@Override

```
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this,"Connecting...", "Please wait...", false,true);

    }
```